# How esignature verification process work?

Tags: web-application, java, digital-signature

I have a web application in which the users will be signing an html report. I know how the digital signature authentication works. But here the user will literally be signing the document (So, Should i digitally sign the document as well?). 
How to verify whether the document is signed by a valid user.

I also want to know in general how the eSignature verification process happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electronic signature (in the cryptographic sense, which I'm assuming is the meaning here) is a method of attesting that the holder of a particular private key has signed the document in it's current state.  The verification of the private key needs to be handled as a separate step.  This can either be by a third party certificate authority or by some procedure to establish the validity of the public key by you.

If it needs to be legally binding, there may be additional requirements in your area and you should consult a lawyer for details about that.